# Difference between torrent P2P sharing and WebRTC P2P sharing?

Tags: webrtc, p2p, rtp, torrent

I have a doubt/misunderstanding.

webRTC uses `RTCDataChannel` API for communicating data P2P.

Torrents also P2P.
Is both the technologies uses same thing in its core ? or any difference is there ?

If there is any difference then can we create some torrent like functionlity using webRTC `RTCDataChannel` API ?

Comment: The normal torrent p2p is different than webrct p2p in terms of protocols and the way they are scaled when dealing with large number of peers

Answer (score 1):

P2P just means that two *peers* (e.g. your computer and my computer) communicate *directly*, *one peer to another*, without requiring a server in the middle. That is all WebRTC and Torrents have in common. Beyond that they're entirely different technologies. Though you *could* probably implement a Torrent-like protocol (enabling file sharing by assembling files from chunks received from various sources) using WebRTC data channels as the underlying transport mechanism.

Comment: Torrents over WebRTC already exists, it's called WebTorrent! https://webtorrent.io

Comment: Well there you go, QED. 